# Javascript - generate dynamic word documents from database or excel

Tags: javascript, cpu-word

I have a word document that will use a macro to change some values dynamically from an excel file. I need to generate a lot of document and the macro will stop work if something into the document will change. I'm looking for a way to use the word document as a template and change the values using javascript. Is there any library or word API I can use to achive this??